# How to fill in the fields with values in a form based on an item clicked ( ASP.NET Core Razor page)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

Coffee shop is created with ASP.NET Core Razor page. Coffee Model created and all available coffee is stored in a db (ef core).
We have two pages. First page shows a table of all coffee (id, title, cost, ...)info. Each coffee has an Edit "button".

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model._coffeeItems)
        {....
                <td>
                    @item.Price &euro; 
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a asp-action= "GetCoffeeItem" >Edit</a> 
                    <a asp-action="RemoveCoffeeItem" >Delete</a>
                </td> ...
```

When clicked should be redirected to an Edit page with a form. All fields must be filled with coffee information for easier edit.

In First page CoffeeItemProvider.cs:

```
public async Task<FoodItem> GetCoffeeItem(int id)
        {
            var item = await _db.CoffeeItems
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);

            return item;
        }
public async Task UpdateCoffeeItem(int id, CoffeeItem item)
        {
            _db.CoffeeItems.Update(item);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

And in the Edit page:

```
<form asp-action="UpdateCoffeeItem">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control"  value = ""/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

How can I fill in the input f.ex. Name with value = "@item.Name"?

Is there any way to make GetCoffeeItem to take in id from First page item when clicked - call GetCoffeeItem- get item - and then redirect to /Edit page with item and assign value = "@item.Smth"?

Comment: There are no controllers or actions in Razor Pages. Are you sure you are not using MVC?

Comment: @MikeBrind, correct it's a service

Comment: @MariaHussey What do you mean by "it's a service"? If you mean a web-service then why are you using Razor/cshtml?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
...
<td>
    <a asp-action="GetCoffeeItem" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a>
    <a asp-action="RemoveCoffeeItem" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
</td>
...
```

and in GetCoffeeItem return the Edit view instead, e.g.:

```
return View("Edit", coffeeModel);
```

Comment: what is asp-route-id? does it require any assignments?

Comment: I strongly recommend avoiding using hardcoded action names in tag-helpers - instead use `nameof()` to ensure you always have the correct action name string.

Comment: @Dai, for some reason I get View doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: @MariaHussey That is not a helpful error message description. Please provide more details: is it an exception or just a stdout/log message? What's the stack-trace? **Are you using your debugger? If not, why not?**

Comment: @MariaHussey please make sure you use the correct name when returning the edit view (i.e. replace "Edit" with the actual name).

Comment: @Dai, no I got an error in VSCode : The name 'View' does not exist in the current context [folder]

Comment: @MariaHussey I think you should just start from scratch - it sounds like you're confusing separate project types.

Comment: @MariaHussey I'm not sure of the project type, but your controller should inherit from the 'Controller' class.

Comment: @balinta,  I fixed it all to be Razer Pages

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an EditModel for /Edit page.
redoing a bit @balinta answer.

```
<a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a>


                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" asp-page-handler="delete"
                        asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete
                        </button>
```

And in the Edit.cshtml.cs :

Just added @page "{id:int?}" on the top. and implemented

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)  function.
```